# Where should I place my Monolog custom Handler in my Symfony2 project?

Tags: php, symfony, handler, composer-php, monolog

I have created a handler class that derives from `AbstractProcessingHandler`. I've seen that I can put it in `src/MyNamespace/MyBundle/Monolog/`, but it worries me a bit because this handler is used in several others bundles where I log data. So the other bundles will need MyBundle to work properly, only because of this handler.

I tried to put my handler class in `lib/` but it does not seem to work (maybe I have to do something special with Autoload?).

Or should I create a new bundle specifically for this handler?

Edit: I can't really place my custom handler class in `vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler` because then I would not be able to add it to my git repository: there is a conflict because this folder is managed by another git repository (created by Composer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Monolog's end there is really no restriction on where to put it or how you call it. The key is only that it implements monolog's HandlerInterface or extends from one of the existing handlers.

Now it depends what your handler is, if it's generic stuff that other people could use you could submit it as a pull request to monolog.
If not, you can either create an own composer package for it, or put it in `src/Acme/Monolog/FooHandler` or something like that, so it stays in your application but is clearly out of a bundle. The downside is that you need to configure it as a service in one of your bundles, so you still have some sort of dependency on a bundle there.
Maybe having it as its own bundle would make sense then. But it's quite a lot of boilerplate for just one class.
If all your bundles are application specific and very unlikely to be extracted out of it, having cross-bundles dependencies is fine though IMO.
The dependency is anyway not very strong since one bundle could contain the handler and configure it. The other bundles can still log to monolog, even if the handler isn't present, they can log. It just won't go to that specific handler. Nothing should break.

As you see, it's just a lot of trade-offs, and it's hard to say which solution is the most fitting without knowing more about your project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have your handler class in `lib/` you will need to add the `lib/` folder to your `composer.json`  autoload section. For example:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": ["src/", "lib/"] }
}
```

Take a look at the Composer documentation:

[Basic Usage](http://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading)

[Autoload](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)

Answer (score 0):

I think the common approach here is to use a "Bridge" dir in your Bundle with a clear dependency.  If you have other bundles that rely on this, what we've done is create a ServiceBundle which is basically for all shared services across all bundles within the application.  This might not work well for you if you have plans of distributing this bundle, but may otherwise.